# Intelij -d option doesn't work

Tags: java, intellij-15

I have a directory structure like this (I've created `classes` directory and added `-d classes` to the compiler options):
[image: configuration]

But when I hit `compile 'BeerSelect.java'` I got:
[image]

Intelij has created `out` directory and omitted my request about using `classes` directory (`-d` option). I cannot figure it out why.

What I am doing wrong that it compiles to `out` not `classes` directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on your project (`beerV1`) and select `Open Module Settings` (near the bottom). Under `Project`, which is is under `Project Settings` in the left hand list, there should be a `Project compiler output` text box. Make sure this is pointing to your `classes` directory.